# Multiple column Formats in WebForm ListView

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using WebForm with Entity Framework. I have a list view with 5 columns and the data of last column is in another model (had foreign key). I don't know how to combine it.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="view_candidate" SelectMethod="GetAssignedCandidates" ItemType="t_pas.Models.Candidate">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <%#Item.Name %>
         <%#Item.Project %>
         <%#Item.CurrentPosition %>
         <%#Item.PromotedTo %>
         <%-- Here is the column which i have said --%>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: `<%# Item.TheOtherModel.TheField %>`? Doesn't this work?

Comment: <%# Item.TheOtherModel.TheField %>  doesn't work in my situation

Comment: GetAssignedCandidates is my method in *.aspx.cs

Comment: In GetAssignedCandidates you would .Include("TheOtherModel") in you query and then use Item.TheOtherModel.TheField

Comment: How about `ItemType="t_pas.Models.Candidate"` . In Candidate model. That filed is foreign key. So i can't combine it to show in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view model, do this:

```
var viewModels = (from candidate in db.Candidates
         select new MyViewModel
         {
             Candidate = candidate,
             OtherModel = Candidate.OtherModel
         })
        .ToList();
```

Now use this custom generated model in your view where you can directly access the value of other model as well.
Note: You have to create a view model interfacing the view and pass data generated from there to the view.